# Assign hotkey to VSCode configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have multiple configurations in `.vscode/launch.json`. How can I assign a hotkey to run each? Right now I have to go to Debug, select the configuration from the dropdown, and run with F5.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on this extension I wrote: [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config).  You can now assign a hotkey to as many launch configs as you want.

Example in `settings.json`:

```
"launches": {
  "ChromeSACC": "Launch Chrome against localhost (BuildSACC)",
  "RunAsArray": ["Launch Chrome against localhost (BuildSACC)", "Launch File (BuildSACC)", "Launch File (TestMultiRoot)"],
  "SACCfile": "Launch File (BuildSACC)",
  "MTRfile": "Launch File (TestMultiRoot)"
}
```

and keybindings:

```
{
    "key": "alt+f",
    "command": "launches.ChromeSACC",
    "args": "restart"
},

{
    "key": "alt+g",
    "command": "launches.RunAsArray",
    "args": "stop/start"
}
```

---

*Previous answer:*

Here is a pretty good solution.  There is a command available for keybinding called

> {
> "command": "workbench.action.debug.selectandstart",
> "key": ""
> }

Search the keyboard shortcuts for it and assign a hotkey.  Then you can quickly open a dropdown panel with your launch tasks, when you select one it starts automatically.   Saves opening the debug panel and hitting F5.